# Intead of update & after update on same table not fired?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two trigger one is `Instead of update` and other is `after update` on same table for same task but after updation only Instead of trigger is fired while if i have two after trigger then both are fired on updation. what's reason for that happened?

```
create trigger tr_tmp_instead on emp  
 Instead of update  
 as   
 begin  
 declare @name varchar(50),@message varchar(200)='Updated name Entered Successfully';  
 select @name=d.name from inserted d;  
 insert into tmp_Instead values(getdate(),@message,@name)  
 Print 'Trigger Fired, Updated name Entered Successfully Into tmp_Instead Table..' 

 end


create trigger tr_tmp on emp  
 after update  
 as   
 begin  
 declare @name varchar(50),@message varchar(200)='Updated name Entered Successfully';  
 select @name=d.name from inserted d;  
 insert into tmp values(getdate(),@message,@name)  
 Print 'Trigger Fired, Updated name Entered Successfully Into tmp Table..'  
 end
```

Comment: Why should the after_update trigger fire, when you do the update in the tmp_instead table?

Answer (score 0):

An `INSTEAD OF` trigger overrides the default action it's defined on.

When you call an `UPDATE` on `emp`, no actual update happens to `emp` and `AFTER UPDATE ON emp` never fires.

Comment: Thanks, sir your statement "When you call an UPDATE on emp, no actual update happens to emp and AFTER UPDATE ON emp never fires" understood me deeply that why 'after update' had not fired.. thank you once again..